# Selenium headless browser - setting default page zoom

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, python, chrome

I have a problem with browser zoom in Google Chrome and FireFox.
I have one button that is overlapped by another element (my page always have 100% zoom and is very bad for me because a lot of elements are invisible).

I found one solution but it works only before page reload:

```
 driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.8)";')
```

I am looking for a solution in headless browser mode (I use Selenium+Python).

Comment: And users are also going to zoom? Maybe fix the page?

Comment: yes, all page going zoom